# How to write initial conditions in matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I have a second-order initial value problem like $2y''+ 2y' + 1y = 0$ and I am given $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0) = -4$ how do I write these initial conditions in the matrix form for the matrix written in $Y=AY$ where $A$ is the matrix? I already know how to convert the overall equation into first order, so the matrix would be

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    -1/2 & -1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

but how do I "convert" the initial values?

I'm looking for an answer in the form

$$ y(0) = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a \\
    b  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Well, what do the elements of $Y$ in the converted equation represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$2y''+ 2y' + 1y = 0 ,y(0) = 1 ,y'(0) = -4$$

Let $x_1 = y$, hence

$$x_1' = y' = x_2 \\ x_2' = y'' = \dfrac{1}{2}(-2 y' - y) = \dfrac{1}{2}(-2 x_2 - x_1)$$

For the initial conditions:

$$x_1(0) = y(0) = 1\\x_2(0) = y'(0) = -4$$

In matrix form

$$X'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\ -\dfrac{1}{2} & -1\end{bmatrix}X(t), ~~~X(0) = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ -4
    \end{bmatrix}$$

You can see other worked examples [*here*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsDE.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The usual conversion to a system involves introducing a new variable $u = y'$ and finding 2 equations in $u$ and $y$. Similarly, the condition $y'(0)=-4$ can be converted to a condition in terms of $u$ without derivatives.

Comment: Can you explain that further? I also edited the question a little so it's easier to see what I'm asking